# Create a list of years from todays year to smallest year in current data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table called emp. This table contains a field which holds numbers which is actually a 4 digits year. I would like to create an output which makes takes today's year and creates a sequential list which will end on the smallest value of this field (sysdate to smallest value).

I know how to get all the dates with the values:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM emp;
```

But how do I fill in all the gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (where `x` would be replaced with your table)

```
with x as (
    select 2001 yr from dual union all
    select 1994 from dual
 )
 select yr + level - 1
   from (select min(yr) yr
           from x)
 connect by level <= extract(year from sysdate) - yr + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Trying to understand why the numbers 2001 and 1994?

Comment: @user2924127 - I just picked a couple of random numbers that had gaps in order to demonstrate the problem since you didn't have any sample data in your question.

Comment: O I see, i thought it was something important! Thanks I have modified it an it works great!